# How to scale image in java ? I need the algorithm not pre-deffinition function

Tags: java, image-processing

I try to implement a simple example for scaling `BufferedImage` in java but code isn't working!

If you have another suggestion for me, please share it! :D

This is my code, but I want to implement a separate function for `BufferedImage` scaling.

Thanks for your help!

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Scale extends JPanel{

    public static void main(String []args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.add(new Translation());
        f.setSize(750, 600);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        double scaleFactorX = 2.0;
        double scaleFactorY = 2.0;
        BufferedImage img = null;
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("img.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth() * scaleFactorX, img.getHeight() * scaleFactorY, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Painting methods can be called by Swing many times per second.  Do not read your image file in a paint method—do it in the constructor, and keep the image in a field of your object.  Also, the final argument to Graphics.drawImage should be `this` rather than null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change `f.add(new Translation())` to `f.add(new Scale())`. 
The result of calculating with an `int` and a `double` will result in a `double`. So parse the result of your calculations to `int` e.g `img.getWidth() * scaleFactorX` -> `(int)(img.getWidth() * scaleFactorX)`. 
See the code below:

```
public class Scale extends JPanel{

  double scaleFactorX = 2.0;//TODO eventually change through constructor?
  double scaleFactorY = 2.0;

  public static void main(String []args){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.add(new Scale());
    f.setSize(750, 600);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    scaleImage((Graphics2D) g);//Call separate function
  }

  //Scales the image from "img.jpg"
  private void scaleImage(Graphics2D g) {        
    BufferedImage img = null;
    BufferedImage image = null;//is never used?!
    try {
      img = ImageIO.read(new File("img.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Graphics2D g2d = g;
    if(img != null) {
      g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
      g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, (int)(img.getWidth() * scaleFactorX), (int)(img.getHeight() * scaleFactorY), null);
    }else{
      System.out.println("Image not found!");
    }
  }
}
```